# How would I link module-page-cache into my theme?

Tags: theme, custom-theme

what would be correct spelling for the module?

`Magento_Page-Cache` , `Magento_Page-cache` , `Magento_Page_Cache` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct name should be: `Magento_PageCache`

if you want to override `template(.phtml)`, theme file path will be:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_PageCache/templates

For `layout(.xml)` it should be:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_PageCache/layout

Comment: Thank you this solution is correct!

Comment: Welcome @Bovolio :)