# Copy Luma Layered Navigation to Blank Theme

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Please, can anyone provide instructions on how to copy the Luma Layered Navigation into the Magento Blank Theme?

I tried by adding the

> Magento_LayeredNavigation

into

```
app/design/frontend
```

Whilst it does show on the front end - it messes all other parts of the site up for example search is shown as an open state - and the top part of the site is shown on the bottom.

Which other files should I be adding or copying?

Would really appreciate if someone can help me with this

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to deploy static content without any compilation errors after you add the layered navigation module?

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266410/how-would-i-link-module-page-cache-into-my-theme/266411#266411

Answer (score 0):

**Just Copy :-**

```
/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/
```

**Your Theme :-**

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/
```